# Targeting html elements with css not working

Tags: css, angular, innerhtml

I have an html string which I am setting inside Angular here

```html
<div
  [innerHtml]="privacyPolicyHtml"
    class="privacy-policy">
</div>
```

and attempting to target. elements within that string like this

```css
.privacy-policy {
  width: toRem(715px);
  color: #363636;
  margin: toRem(40px) auto;
  font-size: toRem(14px);

  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

However, the changes are not being applied even when not using SASS and just

```
.privacy-policy ul {}
```

Comment: looks like the first code snippet did not get added, I am setting the innerHTMl here <div [innerHtml]="privacyPolicyHtml"
 class="privacy-policy">

</div>

Comment: No worries, I fixed it, you can always [edit].

Comment: Try that `.privacy-policy ::ng-deep ul {....`

Comment: ahh yes, ng-deep is what I needed, thank you!